# Python string to bytearray and back

Tags: python, encode

How can I convert a human readable string to a bytearray and back?

Say I have "Hello World" and want a bytearray and then from a bytearray to the same string?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`bytearray()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?#bytearray):

```
b_array = bytearray('yoyo')
for elem in b_array:
    print elem
```

To convert `b_array` back to string format use [`.decode()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.decode):

```
for elem in b_array.decode():
    print elem
```

Answer (score 6):

In Python 3.6:

```
b_array = bytearray('yoyo'.encode())
for elem in b_array:
    print (elem)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the array module

```
from array import array
s = "hello world"
s = array('B', s)
print s
s.tostring()
#or s = s.tostring()
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python >= 3.6, to convert a string to a bytearray:

```py
str.encode('utf-8')
```

When it is a constant string, the process can be simpler. For example:

```
b'Hello World'
```

While converting it back:

```
bytes.decode('utf-8')
```