# convert a string of bytearray to a bytearray

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, bytecode

I have a string of bytearray which i want to convert to bytearray in python 3

For example,

```
x = "\x01\x02\x03\x04"
```

I get the x variable from server, it is a string but content is byte array, how to convert it to byte array. Really stuck at it. Thanks

Comment: You can ``encode`` the string to a bytes object. It would be easier to directly operate on the initial data - TCP (etc.) only transmits bytes, so having a string means you already converted it *from* bytes to a string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: convert string to byte array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11624190/python-convert-string-to-byte-array)

Comment: Also duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32675679/convert-binary-string-to-bytearray-in-python-3 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29177788/python-string-to-bytearray-and-back

Comment: Also: [Python convert strings of bytes to byte array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51754731/2745495)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `encode` a string to a `bytes` object and convert that to a `bytearray`, or convert it directly given some encoding.

```
x = "\x01\x02\x03\x04"      # type: str
y = x.encode()              # type: bytes
a = bytearray(x.encode())   # type: bytearray
b = bytearray(x, 'utf-8')   # type: bytearray
```

Note that `bytearray(:str, ...)` [is specified to use `str.encode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?#func-bytearray), so the later two practically do the same. The major difference is that you have to specify the encoding explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ord](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html?#ord) to convert each byte in the string to an integer. `bytearray` takes an iterable of integers as an argument, so

```
x = "\x01\x02\x03\x04"
b = bytearray(ord(c) for c in x) # bytearray(b'\x01\x02\x03\x04')
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

x = bytes(x, 'utf-8')

Now type(x) is bytes.